# Ending a form after you close the div, bad practive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap, specifically the forms and modals. My main form is inside the modal-body, but the submit buttons need to be in the modal-footer. This would mean I have to close a div and open a new one *inside* the form, as shown below.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </form>
                </div>
```

For reference, this is what the modal looks like: [image: http://i.imgur.com/NPEnlDs.png]

I am curious as to whether this is correct practice, or there is another way this should be approached (all I could think of is having the form tags Outside the modal-body tags).

Comment: Any decent IDE can tell you that's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `<form>` tag so it encompasses the entire `modal-body` div.

Do not use incorrect nesting of tags.

```
<form>
  <div class="modal-body">    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, that looks much more pleasing; will tick when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `<div class="modal-body">` inside and the `</form>` outside your form:

```
                    <form>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```